# How do we clean out JSP's .class files when we re-deploy our application on JBoss?

Tags: jsp, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, .class-file

I'm using JBOss 7.1.3.AS with Java 7.  It is not an option to upgrade at this time.  I notice that when our .jsp files get converted into .class files, they are placed here

```
$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/work/jboss.web/default-host
```

How do we force all the .class files to be removed upon deploying our application (we would like these files re-generated)?  We deploy by running

```
touch $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/myapp.dodeploy
```

but we're open to another method if it solves the problem IL mention above.

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss AS 7.1.x there is no feature to delete the JSP cache under the folder $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/work/jboss.web/default-localhost/$YOUR_WEB_CONTEXT. In JBoss AS 7.2 new feature is system property is included which will delete JSP cash files when context root of the application is destroyed.

In JBoss AS 7 you can set the system property *org.jboss.as.web.deployment.DELETE_WORK_DIR_ONCONTEXTDESTROY* to *true* to delete the JSP cache each time on context destroy. The default for this property is false. You can use this property to remove .java and .class files to ensure that JSP sources are recompiled.

Comment: Is this feature only available in JBoss 7.2 and higher?  I tried it for my 7.1.3 instance and its not working.

Comment: Yes this feature is available in 7.2 and higher release